# opencv VideoCapture d-link DCS-930L

Tags: opencv, video-capture, ip-camera

I am trying to access my ip camera fom opencv without success.

```
VideoCapture capture("http://IP/MJPEG.CGI?.mjpeg&user=username&password=mypassword")
```

when trying using VLC it's works :

```
http://IP/MJPEG.CGI?.mjpeg
```

then VLC ask for username&password and it's fine.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Just a blind guess: did you try adding "&.mjpg" to the end of the URL (so it ends with &password=mypassword&.mjpg) ?

Comment: yes . and ".mjpeg" also

Answer (score 4):

Done Successfully using the following:

```
http://username:password@ip/video.cgi?.mjpg
```