# OpenCV video capture from D-Link DCS-930LB

Tags: java, opencv, video-capture, ip-camera

I am having problem to capture the video feed from the camera mentioned above. The code works fine when I'm using my internal webcamera. The code is grabbed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535645/ip-camera-with-opencv-in-java). The error messages that I receive are the same as posted in that link as well.

**Update**

When I copy the link http://usrname:pwd@ipaddress/video.cgi?.mjpg into my browser, it works fine and the stream is displayed. Although, I cannot access the camera using the same URL in Java.

**What I have done**

I have tried to follow this [LINK @ StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610479/unable-to-get-video-feed-from-d-link-dcs-932l-using-opencv), but no success there. I thought it might help since the camera is similar (I mean that I alter the URL according to the example).

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22202666/opencv-videocapture-d-link-dcs-930l), where the camera seems to be the same as the one I have. This does not work either.

**My code is the following:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;

public class OpenCVTest {

    public OpenCVTest() {

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture(
            "http://username:password@IP-address:8080/video.cgi?.mjpg");
    // VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture(0);
    if (camera.isOpened()) {
        System.out.println("Video is captured");
    } else {
        System.out.println("");
    }
    VideoCamera cam = new VideoCamera(camera);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(cam);
    frame.setSize(800, 800);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    while (camera.isOpened()) {
        cam.repaint();

    }

   }

}
```

The username is replaced with the actual username and the password is replaced with the actual password, and so is the IP-address.

The other class used is as follows.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class VideoCamera extends JPanel {
    VideoCapture camera;

    public VideoCamera(VideoCapture cam) {

    camera = cam;

}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public BufferedImage Mat2BufferedImage(Mat m) {

    int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;
    if (m.channels() > 1) {
        type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;
    }
    int bufferSize = m.channels() * m.cols() * m.rows();
    byte[] b = new byte[bufferSize];
    m.get(0, 0, b); // get all the pixels
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(m.cols(), m.rows(), type);
    final byte[] targetPixels = ((DataBufferByte) img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, targetPixels, 0, b.length);
    return img;

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Mat mat = new Mat();

    if (camera.read(mat)) {
        System.out.print("IMAGE");

    }

    BufferedImage image = Mat2BufferedImage(mat);
    // Mat gray = turnGray(mat);
    // MatOfRect objects = new MatOfRect();
    // CascadeClassifier cas = new CascadeClassifier();
    // cas.detectMultiScale(gray,objects);
    // Mat thresh = threash( gray);

    // BufferedImage image = Mat2BufferedImage(thresh);
    g.drawImage(image, 10, 10, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null);

}

public Mat turnGray(Mat img)

{
    Mat mat1 = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(img, mat1, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
    return mat1;
}

public Mat threash(Mat img) {
    Mat threshed = new Mat();
    int SENSITIVITY_VALUE = 100;
    Imgproc.threshold(img, threshed, SENSITIVITY_VALUE, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
    return threshed;
   }

}
```

I don't know if it matters, but I cannot get it to work with my webcamera if I remove

```
if (camera.read(mat)) {
    System.out.print("IMAGE");
}
```

from the VideoCamera class. It seems to me that the program should run even if I remove a print out. Nevertheless, my problem is that I want it to run with my IP-camera; I don't really care about my other cameras.

I am greatful for all help.